# Zend 2 equivalent of Laravel 4 Route Filter

Tags: php, zend-framework, laravel, zend-framework2

I'm new to Zend 2, I started first with laravel and I need something to do that I know **Laravel's Route Filter** can solve but I'm using Zend 2.

[Laravel Route Filter](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters)

I checked the documentation of Zend 2 and I can't seem to find it.

I need to do some logging and stuffs only on selected routes and I don't want to add that code on every actions of every routes because I have over 50 different routes here, but in laravel I could make use of route filter so that in selected routes, it will go first in the filter before going to that route.

In laravel's route:

```
Route::get('route1',array('before'=>'generic','uses'=>'GenericController@getIndex'));
Route::get('route2',array('before'=>'generic','uses'=>'GenericController@getIndex'));
Route::filter('generic', 'RouteFilter');
```

Comment: Have you seen zend's routematch?

Comment: http://www.masterzendframework.com/tutorial/use-zend-framework-2-routematch-for-dynamic-routing

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Laravel before, but I followed to the link and I am very afraid to say that,

**No, it does not exist**

You will have use the controller:

```
public function somethingAction()
{
   if (!condition true) {
      return $this->notFoundAction();
      // or return $this->redirect()->toRoute('MyRoute');
   }

   // Route is filtered
}
```

You can also attach a callback to the `MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE` event:

```
public function(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function(EventInterface $e) {
        // check the route and do whatever you like
        $matchedRouteName = $event->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
        if ($matchedRouteName = 'admin')  {// or whatever you want to check
           // check if user is admin
        }
   });
}
```

Not only `MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE`, there are a lot of events triggered such as `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH`. You just need to attach a callback function!
For, full list of all the Mvc Events, view [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html) link!

Comment: I see, so you mean to say that there is no other way other than adding  the filter in all of the controllers? About your second suggestion, I think that is what I need, where do I put code? And can you give an example of how to check for a route?